# Assigning exact to react router causes problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to add `exact` keyword to my private router but it is not rendering the component. It works when it's a normal route. Here is my auth code:

```
<AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home}/>
            </Switch>
          </div>

        </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
```

Based on firebase auth state change. I pass the currentUser using auth context provider:

```
<AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
```

code for private route:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest}) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps) =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps}/>
          )
          : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: where is `currentUser` coming from and what does is hold about the current user?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Your question is too vague to answer. At a glance you've probably got the exact route on the wrong part. Try putting exact on the '/' route instead of the '/login' route.

Comment: ```currentUser``` is from my authcontext provider.

Comment: @nihilok it is not working either.

Comment: What is the behaviour that you're getting?

Comment: @nihilok When I run the above code it works. But when I add the exact to private route. It is not working.

Comment: The reason to add exact to the private route is that I want to redirect from Home to another component on a button click.

Comment: I think you'd need to show us your actual private route component, rather than just the return statement.

Comment: @nihilok question updated